# ImageJ Plugin: Status Bar and Progress Bar do not update

Tags: imagej

I am writing a plugin for ImageJ. I am attempting to show progress using the commands

```
IJ.showStatus(String message)
```

and

```
IJ.showProgress(int currentIndex, int finalIndex)
```

the plugin runs to completion, but none of the status updates display. Is there a way to force the display? I have tried forcing a repaint and waiting after the showStatus call

```
IJ.getInstance().repaint();
IJ.wait(1);
```

but this has no effect

Answer (score 2):

The time consuming computations were being called as a result of a button push. This tied up the UI thread.

I was able to resolve the problem by creating a new thread to run the computations.

Comment: For anyone interested in this... https://forum.image.sc/t/ij-showprogress-in-java/3233 explains how to create such thread